# issues putting char pointers into 2d array of char pointers

Tags: c

I'd love some help here, driving me nuts.

Large file using strtok to split up my lines. I'm trying to separate the first part out, save it into my symbolTblChar[lblCnt]. What I can't seem to understand is why, after pulling from the file , my output becomes so weird

INPUT

```
    "SPACE \n LINE \n A1 \n A2"
```

Code

```
char* symbolTblChar[MAX_SYMBOLS][100];
int lblCnt = 0;
char line[LINE_SIZE];
char* chk;


    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {                                   
            chk = (char*)strtok( line, delims );
            printf("Adding %s to symbol table", chk);
            *symbolTblChar[lblCnt]=chk + '\0';
            lblCnt++;
            int t;
            for(t = 0; t < lblCnt; t++)
                     printf("%s\n", *symbolTblChar[t]);                     
    }
```

Output:

```
    Adding SPACE to symbol table
    Adding LINE to symbol table
    LINE
    Adding A1 to symbol table
    A1
    A1
    Adding A2 to symbol table
    A2
    A2
    A2
```

Comment: Pointers are not strings and there is no pre-made string class in C. I'm afraid this whole code doesn't make any sense. In particular, `*symbolTblChar[lblCnt]=chk + '\0';` doesn't make any sense and suggests that you believe you are doing some kind of hard copies while you are not, you are merely assigning addresses. I'd step back and study pointers and arrays more before attempting this.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. The hard + NULL was a desperate attempt that carried over from C# when I started getting frustrated

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate and store characters. With your code you are storing pointer of character array `line` and it will get overwritten when you read subsequent lines.

You need to do something like

```
*symbolTblChar[lblCnt]= strdup(chk);
```

Also, not sure you need double char pointer as

```
char* symbolTblChar[MAX_SYMBOLS][100];
```

You can work with below which will store `MAX_SYMBOLS` number of strings.

```
char* symbolTblChar[MAX_SYMBOLS];
```

Comment: Thanks, strdup did the trick. I got thrown off since I could access the pointer array from several locations and get the same answer. One edit though. I had to remove the dereference on your first line of suggestion or else I got an int to pointer cast issue.

Comment: @BryanS., Yes, if you follow the suggestion then you need to change the way you using `symbolTblChar`, i.e. do not de-reference it.

Comment: I would recommend to use malloc and memcpy/strcpy instead of strdup, since strdup is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what it is you are trying to do. In addition to Rohan's answer, you are also stumbling over the use of `strtok`. While it is somewhat a catch 22, since you are reading a string with symbols separated by `newlines`, you can still make `strtok` work. Understand though, when using `strtok`, your first call to `strtok` uses the pointer to the string as its first argument:

```
chk = strtok (line, delims);
```

while all subsequent calls to `strtok` use `NULL` as the first argument:

```
chk = strtok (NULL, delims);
```

What is nice about `strtok` is it was tailor-made for parsing an entire string in a `for` loop format. e.g.:

```
for (chk = strtok (line, delims); chk; chk = strtok (NULL, delims))
```

Putting that together, and cleaning up `symbolTblChar[MAX_SYMBOLS]` to simply be an array of pointers to `char`, rearranging your logic a bit, provides the following example. I guessed at what you would need for `LINE_SIZE` and what would work for `MAX_SYMBOLS` (adjust as required):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_SIZE    128
#define MAX_SYMBOLS   32

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *symbolTblChar[MAX_SYMBOLS] = {NULL};
    char line[LINE_SIZE] = {0};
    char *chk = NULL;
    char delims[] = " \n";
    int lblCnt = 0;
    int t = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (fp != stdin && !fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nCollecting Symbols:\n");
    while (fgets (line, LINE_SIZE, fp)) 
    {                                   
        for (chk = strtok (line, delims); chk; chk = strtok (NULL, delims)) {
            printf ("  Adding %s to symbol table\n", chk);
            symbolTblChar[lblCnt] = strdup (chk);
            lblCnt++;

            /* check for MAX_SYMBOLS */
            if (lblCnt == MAX_SYMBOLS) {
                fprintf (stderr, "warining: MAX_SYMBOLS limit reached.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* close file if not stdin */
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    /* output */
    printf ("\nSymbols:\n");
    for (t = 0; t < lblCnt; t++)
        printf("  %s\n", symbolTblChar[t]);

    /* free allocated memory */
    for (t = 0; t < lblCnt; t++)
        free (symbolTblChar[t]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

Using your sample input provides:

```
$ printf "SPACE \n LINE \n A1 \n A2\n" | ./bin/symbltbl

Collecting Symbols:
  Adding SPACE to symbol table
  Adding LINE to symbol table
  Adding A1 to symbol table
  Adding A2 to symbol table

Symbols:
  SPACE
  LINE
  A1
  A2
```

**Note:** you can of course remove the `Adding X ...` intermediate print line when you are done with it. Now, even though it may not be apparent, you need to `free` the memory associate with each symbol added to `symbolTblChar` using `strdup` (which both allocates and copies its argument to a new memory location). You can see that taking place at the end of `main`.

If this isn't what you intended, let me know. After looking at the question and what you were doing, this seemed like your logical intent. Let me know if you have any questions.

**File Input:** note, you can also provide an input filename as the first argument to the program and the program will read from the file instead of `stdin`. For example, the input file:

```
$ cat symbols.txt
  SPACE
  LINE
  A1
  A2
```

**Output Reading from File**

```
$ /bin/symbltbl symbols.txt

Collecting Symbols:
  Adding SPACE to symbol table
  Adding LINE to symbol table
  Adding A1 to symbol table
  Adding A2 to symbol table

Symbols:
  SPACE
  LINE
  A1
  A2
```